# Flutter desktoop Linux Appliaction not working After installed it from snapstore(ubuntu store)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, flutter-desktop, snapcraft, flutter-linux

I have developed the Flutter Linux desktop application. In debugging mode application working fine. The application was also published on snapcraft(ubuntu store) but when we installed this application from the store , the application was not listed in the application menu list(ubuntu app list) . it will open  via terminal only

can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to make it appear in the menu you have to create the gui folder inside the snap snap/gui your desktop file and your image for the application icon
the desktop file with the following information

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=paneladmin
Comment=flutterapp
Exec=paneladmin
Icon=${SNAP}/meta/gui/logoadmin.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

your desktop file should have the same name as your yaml file and exec the name of your yaml in the app name part
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/desktop-files-for-menu-integration/13115